# Phone's download speed doesn't go over 10 Mbps(1.2 MBps)

Tags: wi-fi, networking, network-signal

I have an ASUS Zenfone Max Pro M1(X00_TD). Lately, I have noticed that my phone's downloading or uploading speeds don't go over 10 to 15 Mbps. It has a 2.4 G wifi and easily used to give me 40-60 Mbps 2-3 months ago. But now I don't know why the speeds never go above 15 Mbps.

Initially, I thought my ISP maybe down or the server may not be giving off above 15, but I cross verified it 50 times with other devices.

It doesn't go above 15 Mbps even on cellular data.

The ISP is fine(100 Mbps).
It doesn't go above 15 even in speed tests. How can I fix this?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Try clearing download manager's cache and data (it's a system app and you will need enable "show system apps" in app listing //If that doesn't help try a download manager from Play store // last resort clear wifi data//If nothing helps verify if the behavior is same in safe mode (Google how to enter safe mode for your device)

Comment: Nothing helps, and the behaviour is the same in Safe Mode. What to do? @beeshyams

Comment: If it is the same device which is mentioned in your previous question, I would backup data and do a factory-reset

Comment: Trying the same now. Thanks.

Comment: @beeshyams Did a factory reset, it didn't bring any improvement.

Comment: That's unfortunate. Try flashing the stock ROM if it is possible or head to the service centre //unless you want to root it and try flashing a custom ROM // Factory reset is a nuclear option and if that doesn't fix things, I doubt there is a solution

Comment: Thank you so much, will go to the service center. @beeshyams

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue got fixed, the issue was with the ROM. I had flashed a stock ROM from ASUS' website a month or so ago and due to that even factory resetting didn't help. I flashed a new Pixel Experience ROM on it by unlocking the bootloader and it fixed the issue. I'm now getting full speeds, 50 Mbps+